# Android multi row items in list view

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i'm trying to change rows in list view by check all ArrayList item in `getView`. if `item.getSend_status()` is `-1` convertView must be inflate `layout_message_content_list_rtl` otherwise `layout_message_content_list_ltr`.

in my `getView` i wrote that, but after scroll listview `else` dont work and for all of items only `layout_message_content_list_ltr` inflated, for example if i have two item in `ArrayList` as an this structure:

```
public class RowItems{
    int send_status;
    String title;
}
```

in item one `send_status` is `-1` and second item is `1`, my list view must be have different item, but thats not working correctly and i have only on inflate in listview

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder   mViewHolder;
    MessagesList item = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        if (item.getSend_status() == -1) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_message_content_list_rtl, null);
        } else{
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_message_content_list_ltr, null);
        }
        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {
        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    mViewHolder.fillItems(this, item, position);

    return convertView;
}
```

Logcat:

this result is for `Log.e("Send_status: ",item.getSend_status()+"");` into `fillItems`:

```
E/Send_status:﹕ -1
E/Send_status:﹕ 1
E/Send_status:﹕ 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work and is the expected behaviour. We should begin by understanding what `convertView` stands for!

To re-use views, android recycles an already inflated view of a out-of-viewport position to your getView() method with the name `convertView`. For homogeneous lists(single type of layout), this works out perfectly, because the `convertView` will have the same layout as your new view. So android says, "Hey, the view is already inflated, take it! Just update the items in it with the data for that position!."

Now what if you have two types of layouts. Fear not, this is accommodated in the Adapter's architecture!

You need  to override following two methods in your adapter's code:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2; //Number of different layouts in the list. "rtl" and "ltr" = 2 in your case.
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    MessagesList item = getItem(position);
    if (item.getSend_status() == -1) {
        return 0; // for rtl
    }
    else {
        return 1; // for ltr
    }
    //The return value must be less than the view type count
}
```

Now, in your `getView()` method, do this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder   mViewHolder;
    MessagesList item = getItem(position);
    View newView = convertView;

    if (newView == null) {
        if (getItemViewType(position)==0) {
            newView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_message_content_list_rtl, parent, false);
        } else {
            newView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_message_content_list_ltr, parent, false);
        }
        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder(newView);
        newView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {
        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) newView.getTag();
    }

    mViewHolder.fillItems(this, item, position);

    return newView;
}
```

Comment: not working sir. all of items inflated `layout_message_content_list_rtl` layout

Comment: That means all your messages items have `sendStatus` set to -1? Can you log it and verify?

Comment: Add log statements in the getView() code. Log both `position` and the `getItemViewType(position)`.

Comment: whats `getViewTypeCount`, my array list size is not `2` can i dont use that?

Comment: That is the number of layouts that you have. Which is 2 -  `rtl` and `ltr`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84285/discussion-between-awanish-raj-and-mahdi-pishguy).